Dynamic Column Value in Power BI
I am having an issue where I don't know where to start if I am honest.
I have a list of projects with their associated budgets, sales etc. which need to be viewed by multiple departments.
It's essentially like
Project A needs to be seen by Departments 1,2 and 4
Project B needs to be seen by departments 1,2 and 3
Project C needs to be seen by 3 and 4.
And so on.
I can do it through calculated boolean columns to determine if each project is needed by department 1, another for 2 etc. And then using many many measures for each calculated column and a switch measure bases on a selected value in another measure to bring it all together but I can't help think there might be an easier way.
Hopefully that made sense but any help would be appreciated?

It sounds like another table would be easier. Isn't there a query that will give the Projects and Departments so it's dynamic for future projects? Then you create a relationship in PBI between the tables.

Creating a table per Department? I can do a dynamic list as you say but there is between 10 and 15 departments

No, I mean a single query/table with the department and projects. One column for Project and another for Dept. Then you select Dept 1, it would show Projects A and B due to the two Dept 1 records in the new table with the relationship to the current table by project.

If you mean User by department, you can implement RLS (Row Level Security) for your report. Once you are done, only designated Department/User can see their own data from a combined data set. You can find some details here in the below link-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/security/service-admin-row-level-security
